# Как из меню открыть конкретный таб?

Tags: android, java

Есть класс

```
public class BasicActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

от которого наследуются все `Activity`, чтобы иметь общее меню. И есть

```
public class MainTabs extends TabActivity.
```

Как создать метод в `BasicActivity`, который будет открывать определённую вкладку в `MainTabs`?

```
public class BasicActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.m_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.call_tab:
            ...
            break;
        default:
            return false;       
    }
    return true;
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А в чем проблема?
У TabHost есть метод setCurrentTab(String tabID). 
Вам просто нужно привязать свои пункты меню к id табов.

Comment: Как мне в BasicActivity написать обращение к TabHost, чтобы выполнить эту привязку, т.е. метод setCurrentTab(String tabID)? Если Вы такое использование метода имели ввиду.

Comment: Я искал это: TabHost tabHost=(TabHost) getParent().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
ну и затем конечно:
tabHost.setCurrentTab(3);